# how to convert long double to string format in Xcode ? or how to solve error "use of undeclared identifier 'to_string' "

Tags: c++, xcode, string, macos, double

this code works in microsoft visual c++, but when i run this in Xcode, it give me error No member named 'to_string' in namespace 'std'

```
double learningRates[] = {0.00015, 0.00065, 0.00075, 0.0015, 0.0045, 0.0065, 0.0075, 0.055};

long double learning_Value = learningRates[learningRate_Index];

string pathtotal_weight_Bias= pathWeightBias +"/" + "best_weight_Bias" + convertInt(MaxEpochs) +"_LR"+ to_string(learning_Value)+".xml";
```

even if i used std::to_string(learning_Value), even than it gives the same error.

Kindly guide me in this regards. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if its related but to_string is a C++11 feature.

Comment: It probably means your compiler isn't configured to accept C++11. I've no idea how to specify that in Xcode, though.

Comment: so? how can i fix it in xcode?

Comment: You probably need to configure the Xcode project to support C++11.

Comment: if i do that, then there arrises more errors, currently i made it to libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library). If i change it to libc++(llvm c++ standard library with c++11 support) than it creates more errors.

Comment: The libstdc++ that's in XCode 5 doesn't support to_string, so if you want to keep using it you'll have to start using `libc++` across the board.

Comment: still have same problem, If i use that than i face another error of Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Comment: Rather than going down that rabbit-hole (figuring out your build problems), you could just rewrite the code to use something other than `to_string`. I realize it's a lazy answer, but it will get the job done in this case. The undefined symbols issue could be related to linking to C++ code that was built with `libstdc++`, and so will not link to code that is built with `libc++` - you will need to rebuild everything with `libc++`.

Comment: i am trying to use NSSTring instead of to_String(). But not successful till now. any suggestion in that regards

Comment: Use NSString, and consult the [NSString documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Comment: (And, at the very least, if you are still going to attempt to use C++ functions you need to make the module name end with ".mm", not ".m".)

Answer (score 0):

I think [stringWithFormat](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943-CJBEAEHH) might do the trick:

```
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/best_weight_Bias%d_LR%Lf.xml", pathWeightBias, MaxEpochs, learning_Value];
```

Comment: thanks, but i used another code, of making a template of string... anyhow thanks alot..